# Pyspark Dataframe Efficient ways for O(n^2) Complexity Looping

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, pyspark, iteration

I have a pyspark datafram as the following. I need to check the longest common subsequence between the text field (3rd column) and return a new dataframe that crosses a certain threshold in similarity value. So, the complexity in the simple array would be O(n^2). I was wondering how to get this effect for a distributed system using pyspark. I got one idea by using join on the data frame, however, it is very costly in terms of computation when the dataframe size increases. It would be great if you please provide some information about some efficient or 'right' way to do this.

```
--------------------------
path | startline | text
--------------------------
 p1  |      15   | hello
--------------------------
 p2  |      8    | world
--------------------------
 p3  |      5    | AAA
--------------------------
```

My current code structure is as follows:

```
#convert the pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe
#df was in csv format in pandas dataframe
spark_dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)

def lcs(row):
    #need to run Longest common subsequence on texts from two rows
    return (row.path, row.startline, row.text, lcs_sim)

transformed_spark_df = spark_df.rdd.map(lcs)
```

Comment: Can you please give examples for the DFs? Are you suggesting that for every value in one DF, we have to scan the other for that value? What does the expected output look like? Can you not convert at least 1 to a dict?

Comment: I meant for a given text (e.g., "hello"), we need to compare against all the remaining texts in a sequential programming approach, such as using simple list of python or so... @roganjosh

Comment: ok, I'll take that, but I had other questions. Can you not create a dictionary for one of them?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you are suggesting for creating dictionary... will it be easier that way...? currently I have only a pyspark dataframe.. @roganjosh

Comment: Well, dictionary lookups are O(1) so depending on your required output you might be able to get a good speedup. Without seeing representative inputs and outputs, I can only pontificate on how we might speed this up.

Comment: Edited my post, hope you can better understand the problem I am facing... @roganjosh

Comment: The edit doesn't help me at all btw. I'm trying to get an understanding of the input and required output.

Comment: I hope you understand that I'm not trying to be awkward :) I just want to have enough info that I (and others) might be able to test and try improve. The best is to give us something to run locally. I think this problem can be abstracted away from pyspark.